# Reference.update failed: First argument contains a function in property?

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am getting the following errors when trying to make a simple cloud function which detects a like on the RD, and then ads posts to a user timeline.

**How can I fix the function? What am I doing wrong?**

---

***(2 errors bellow are from the Firebase cloud functions console)***

onPostLike

> Error fetching likers username: Error: Reference.update failed: First argument contains a function in property 'UserFYP.Bke7CYXP31dpyKdBGsiMOEov2q43.0PMdzaOyYBejf1Gh6Pk1RRA5WNJ2.postID.node_.children_.comparator_' with contents = function NAME_COMPARATOR(left, right) {

onPostLike

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined at ServerResponse.json (/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:257:20) at ServerResponse.send (/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:158:21) at likerUIDRef.once.then.catch.error (/workspace/lib/index.js:669:52) at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)

Related Typescript:

```
 function addPersonalizedFYPPosts(whoLikes: string, postUID: string, postID: string) {
      
      //need to use data to fetch my latest likes
      //then I use the likers data to add the new post to his fypTimeline

      const ref = admin.database().ref(`Likes/${postUID}/${postID}/media1`);
      return ref.once("value") 
      .then(snapshot => {

        //use snapshot to get the my latest like ??
        //Now with this ssnapshot we see other people who liked the same post this liker has. get one of their UIDs and see what else they liked add that to thte likers timeline. 

        var i2 = 0

        snapshot.forEach((theChild) => {

          if (i2 == 0) {

            let uid = theChild.key
          
            //do what you want with the uid
  
            //const userWhoAlsoLiked = snapshot.forEach
  
            const likerUIDRef = admin.database().ref(`YourLikes/${uid}`);
            likerUIDRef.once("value")
            .then(snap =>{
              //const username = snap.val()
              
              var i = 0
              snap.forEach((child) => {
                //UserFYP
                if (i == 0) {
                  let timelineID = child.key;
                  let timeStamp = child.child("timeStamp");
                  let newPostID = child.child("postID");
                  let postUid = child.child("uid");
    
                  //admin.database().ref(`UserFYP/${whoLikes}/${timelineID}/`).update(["":""])
                  admin.database().ref(`UserFYP/${whoLikes}/${timelineID}/`).set({"postID": newPostID, "uid": postUid, "timeStamp": timeStamp})
                  .then(slap =>{
                    console.log("Success updating user FYP: " )
                    return Promise.resolve();
                  })
                  .catch(error => {
                    console.log("Error fetching likers username: " + error)
                    response.status(500).send(error);
                  })
                  i++;
                }
                // return;
              })
              
            })
            .catch(error => {
              console.log("Error fetching likers username: " + error)
              response.status(500).send(error)
            })
            
            return;
            
            i2++;
          }
      })

      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log("The read failed: " + error)
        response.status(500).send(error)
      })  

    }

export const onPostLike = functions.database
.ref('/Likes/{myUID}/{postID}/media1/{likerUID}')
.onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
  const uid = context.params.likerUID
  const postID = context.params.postID
  const myUID = context.params.myUID
  //addNewFollowToNotif(uid, followerUID)

  return addPersonalizedFYPPosts(uid,myUID,postID);
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `child()` on a `DataSnapshot` gives you another `DataSnapshot`. So:

```
  snap.forEach((child) => {
    //UserFYP
    if (i == 0) {
      let timelineID = child.key;
      let timeStamp = child.child("timeStamp");
      let newPostID = child.child("postID");
      let postUid = child.child("uid");
```

In this code, your local variables are snapshots, which contains a.o. functions for accessing them. Since you can only write JSON to the database, the snapshots get rejects.

What you're probably looking for is:

```
  snap.forEach((child) => {
    //UserFYP
    if (i == 0) {
      let timelineID = child.key;
      let timeStamp = child.child("timeStamp").val();
      let newPostID = child.child("postID").val();
      let postUid = child.child("uid").val();
```

Comment: If the change I proposed removes the error you got, what you have is a new problem. I recommend posting a new question, as there's a good chance that someone else may know better what causes this new problem that I do.

Comment: Can do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64924179/typeerror-cannot-read-property-get-of-undefined-at-serverresponse-json